# How to convert "Double" to formatted string in VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, double

I was working on small script in VB. 
I need to format a double number which is result of division. 
Thus there could be many digits after decimal places. I need to convert it to String with only two decimals places. 
I used to do it in C# with Double.ToString("0.##"); 
is there any methode like that in VBScript ..
Please help ..

Himanshu

Answer (score 5):

You're going to want the `FormatNumber` function.  `FormatNumber(num, 2)` will give you the number formatted to 2 decimal points.  See the link for more details.

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatnumber.asp